# Perl open3 read pipe handles of gnuplot block

Tags: perl, ipc, gnuplot

I have the following function to plot data using perl + gnuplot. Input data files are quite numerous and about half of them produce invalid ranges and I want to detect and delete those bad files. The function only processes a single file and I could not get it to read any gnuplot output, it just blocks. I tried reading GPR/GPE in vain.

```
sub plot_file {
  my $filename = shift;
  if ($filename =~ m![^\/]+/([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)!) {
    my ($node, $box, $metric) = ($1, $2, $3);
    my $plot_file = "plots/$node.$box.$metric.eps";
    if ($metric !~ /Sqr/) {
      open3(\*GPW, \*GPR, \*GPE, "$gnuplot") or die "no gnuplot";
      print GPW "set terminal postscript 'Consola' 12\n";
      print GPW "NODE      = '$node'\n";
      print GPW "BOX       = '$box'\n";
      print GPW "METRIC    = '$metric'\n";
      print GPW "DATA_FILE = '$filename'\n";
      print GPW "OUT_FILE  = '$plot_file'\n";
      print GPW "set size 1.0,0.5\n";
      print GPW "set title BOX.' - '.NODE.' - '.METRIC\n";
      print GPW "set output OUT_FILE\n";
      print GPW "plot DATA_FILE using 1:2 with lines notitle\n";
      my $skip;
      while (<GPE>) {
        if (/Warning/) {
          system ("rm $plot_file");
          $skip = 1;
          last;
        }
      }
      if (not $skip) {
        system ("epstopdf $plot_file");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external command will probably not produce any output until you close the input stream to that command to tell the command that no more input is expected.
Call

```
close GPW;
```

after your last `print GPW ...` statement.